# PowerShell -replace operator exhibits quirky behavior with particular data

Tags: powershell, replace

The presence of the special PowerShell variable $_ in the replacement string causes odd behavior; I am wondering if there is something about escaping I am missing or if this is just a defect.

The output of this code...

```
$text = "WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4"
$newText = 'new $_ text'
$newText
$text -replace "WORD3",$newText
```

... is this, where $_ is interpolated with the original contents of $text for some reason *during* the replace operation:

```
new $_ text
WORD1 WORD2 new WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4 text WORD4
```

Replace *should* treat its second parameter as a literal--using no interpolation--which is true for most anything, including things that look like regular variables like this:

```
$foo = "HELLO"
$text = "WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4"
$newText = 'new $foo text'
$newText
$text -replace "WORD3",$newText
```

... and its output is:

```
new $foo text
WORD1 WORD2 new $foo text WORD4
```

But the presence of $_ causes interpolation. Similar problem with $$. As far as I can tell no other special variables cause interpolation.

Note that the same problem occurs with inline code like this:

```
$text -replace "WORD3",'new $_ text'
```

I split it out above just to show that the replacement string was correct before the replace operation. Curiously, if I replace the single quotes with double quotes here to *ask* for interpolation, the result is different. That is, this code:

```
$text -replace "WORD3","new $_ text"
```

produces the expected

```
WORD1 WORD2 new  text WORD4
```

not the baffling

```
WORD1 WORD2 new $foo text WORD4
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what you want using

`$text.replace('WORD3','new $_ text')`

this gives the expected output

`WORD1 WORD2 new $_ text WORD4`

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know by now, this is the regex engine having a clashing syntax for capture groups. It's not PowerShell string interpolation happening. You can escape it with `$$`

```
$text = "WORD1 WORD2 WORD3 WORD4"
$newText = 'new $$_ text'
$newText
$text -replace "WORD3", $newText

"WORD1 WORD2 new $_ text WORD4"
```